# SQL to find the most recent active event

Tags: sql, presto

I have 2 tables, requests and events. See below.

```
requests columns: request_id(primary_key), user_id, request_timestamp.

events columns: event_id(primary_key), user_id, event_start_time, event_end_time
```

One thing to note is that given an user id, all of the events duration are mutually exclusive.

Now I'd like to write a SQL to join these 2 tables and generate data as below:

```
request_id, user_id, event_id, event_start_time, event_end_time, request_timestamp
```

There are 2 cases/constraints when doing the joining:

1. If the request is made while an event is active, we should pick it up i.e. `request_timestamp >= events.start_time AND request_timestamp <= events.end_time`. Then done
2. If there is no active events, we need to pick up the event ending just before the request i.e. find all the events associated with the user and filter out events with start_time greater than the request time. Then select the one with the event with the `MAX(end_time)`.

I spent quite a bit of time on this but could not get it right. I think the problem I'm trying to solve is not unique.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  What if there are two active events?

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm using Presto and I just updated the tag. The important part for me is that I learned to leverage branch statement in SQL to do such queries. It does not really matter the type of the database I'm using. My use case ensures the event period is mutually exclusive. So it's not possible there are 2 active events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want one event per request, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select r.*,
       (select e.event_id
        from events e
        where e.user_id = r.user_id and
              e.event_start_time <= request_timestamp
        order by (case when request_timestamp between event_start_time and event_end_time then 1 else 2 end),
                 request_timestamp desc
        limit 1
       ) as event_id
from requests r;
```

You can then `join` back to the events table to get the rest of the information:

```
select r.*, e.*
from (select r.*,
             (select e.event_id
              from events e
              where e.user_id = r.user_id and
                    e.event_start_time <= request_timestamp
              order by (case when request_timestamp between event_start_time and event_end_time then 1 else 2 end),
                       request_timestamp desc
              limit 1
             ) as event_id
      from requests r
     ) r left join
     events e
     on e.event_id = r.event_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I think this is a nice solution. I barely used any branch statement in SQL before. I think the way you use `case when` is really smart here. Thanks again!